# Sass, Compass and Susy in a Rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

Starting a redesign of my site which is using Rails 3.2. I was already using Sass and Compass and for the redesign have thrown all the old styles out and want to add Susy into the mix. Just a few quick questions about how things work before I get going:

I have just added: `config.compass.preferred_syntax :sass` to my `application.rb` file in `/config`, is this correct? Is the `application.rb` file sort of substituting itself for the normal `compass.rb` config file on standard compass projects?

The line I added obviously changes the expected syntax to the sass indented one which I much prefer but it looks like that line is telling compass what syntax I like. Is compass now doing the compiling of the css and not sass? I also read in the sass docs that you can tell it what syntax you prefer, do I need to set them both? I'm just not sure what is doing what function!

I have also added `gem "susy"` into my `Gemfile`, do I need to add `config.compass.require "susy"` to `/config/application.rb`?

Also, If I want to set the fonts_dir, Compass docs state that by default for Rails apps it will default to `public/fonts` but I want to put them in `/app/assets/fonts`. Will that work?

From Compass docs:

> String    The directory where the font files are kept. Standalone
>   projects will default to /fonts. Rails projects will default
>   to "public/fonts".

I hope people will be able to shed some light on these issues for me.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here.  Have you tried anything?  Did you get any errors?

Comment: I have it all working now, just been playing with it since I posted. I basically want to know is, is compass doing all the sass compiling? I need confirmation on what is actually doing what. What parts is sprockets doing now with the asset pipeline. Also, how can I view the compiled css?

Comment: I can't help you beyond Sass/Compass (not a Ruby/Rails programmer).  Compass is a wrapper around Sass that injects a lot of useful things (extensions, extra functions, a less verbose command, etc.).  For those of us using Sass/Compass as a standalone, the compiled CSS file is placed in the directory listed in config.rb.

Comment: I know how to use Compass, use it everyday outside of a Rails app. But it's just what bits are doing what inside of my personal Rails app where I am getting confused. I also, can't seem to find the compiled version of the final css when run from within the Rails app. I'm very confident in it's use outside of Rails though, it is a fantastic library!

Thanks for your help. Maybe someone else will attempt help me out.

Comment: @rctneil rails doesn't compile your stylesheet & javascript assets in development mode that's why you can't find them. In development mode this is done on the fly by the [sprockets-rails](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails) gem (please correct me if I'm wrong here). If you want to compile your assets you could run `rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

No. Compass isn't doing the Sass compiling.

> Sass is an extension of CSS3 which adds nested rules, variables,
>   mixins, selector inheritance, and more. Sass generates well formatted
>   CSS and makes your stylesheets easier to organize and maintain.

All that compass does is adding additional features to Sass so you don't need to program them by yourself.

---

The line `config.sass.preferred_syntax :sass` tells Rails that your generated Sass files should have the Sass syntax (.css.sass) instead of the SCSS syntax (.css.scss).

---

Also no, you don't need to require susy if you added it to the Gemfile and made a `bundle install`. All you need to do is to import it in your application.css file after you have imported compass.

```
@import "compass"
@import "susy"
```